# Adding link color to CSS properties group

Tags: css, hyperlink

Is it possible to specify the hyperlink color within the main CSS properties statement like below? I have tried several variations and no luck.

```
width: 100%;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #693F18;
a.link-color: #fff;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to style a hyperlink: `a` for the link itself, along with the following [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes):

- `a:link` - a normal, unvisited link
- `a:visited` - a link the user has visited
- `a:hover` - a link when the user mouses over it
- `a:active` - a link the moment it is clicked

To change the colour, you're looking for the [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) property.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
a {
  color: cyan;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
}

a:active {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the principal but I was looking to group the hyperlink color in my properties for the "div" statement just for that section.